# How to extract number from string in BATCH

Tags: string, parsing, batch-file

I would like to extract first number, found in a path string.

Some examples

```
c:\dir\release1\temp  should extract: 1
c:\dir\release11\temp  should extract: 11
c:\dir\release1\temp\rel2  should extract: 1
c:\dir\release15a\temp  should extract: 15
```

My current code, that loops trough folder names, and tests if folder name is a number (I need some changes here):

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set line=one\two\three\4\pet\0\sest\rel6\a
rem set line=%cd%
:processToken
for /f "tokens=1* delims=\" %%a in ("%line%") do (
echo Token: %%a
set line=%%b
rem need fix here: need to extract number from string
echo %%a|findstr /r /c:"^[0-9][0-9]*$" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (echo not a number) else (echo number)
)
if not "%line%" == "" goto :processToken
endlocal
```

Thanks!

EDIT:
I wanted to parse number from that path string.
Well I've found solution that checks only last 3 characters of string. It's ok for now.

```
::test last 3 characters
set relno=!token:~-3,3!
echo !token:~-3,3!|findstr /r /c:"^[0-9]*$" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (echo not number) else (echo number)

::test last 2 characters
set relno=!token:~-2,2!
echo !token:~-2,2!|findstr /r /c:"^[0-9]*$" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (echo not number) else (echo number)

::test last character
set relno=!token:~-1,1!
echo !token:~-1,1!|findstr /r /c:"^[0-9]*$" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (echo not number) else (echo number)
```

Comment: What do you expect with your test line? 406 or 4 or 6 or ...?

Comment: what is your problem? what is your question?

Comment: jeb: if string is:"406" it should return whole number: 406

PA: I want to parse number from path string. Already found solution - se EDIT

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, here's a batch only version.  It implements isdigit, walks the input looking for the first digit, and stops and prints the characters between when it hits the end or a non-digit.

This is slow - the longer the input, the slower it is.

```
@setlocal
@echo off
rem extractfirstnumber.bat
rem Given a string possibly containing a number, print the first integer.
rem 123test456 -> 123
rem Note that special characters may not be properly handled.  (e.g. , ;)
rem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120623/how-to-extract-number-from-string-in-batch
set input=%1
if ("%input%") == ("") goto :eof
call :firstnum input output
if not ("%output%") == ("") echo %output%&&goto end_success
goto end_fail

:end_success
endlocal
@exit /b 0

:end_fail
endlocal
@exit /b 1

:firstnum
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
call set "string=%%%~1%%"
set /a index = 0
set return_number=
goto firstnum_loop

:firstnum_loop
if ("!string:~%index%,1!") == ("") goto firstnum_end
set test_char=!string:~%index%,1!
call :isdigit test_char is_digit
rem Found a digit?  Add it to the return.
if ("%is_digit%") == ("true") set return_number=%return_number%%test_char%
rem Found a not-digit?  If we found a digit before, end.
if ("%is_digit%") == ("false") if not ("%return_number%") == ("") goto firstnum_end
set /a index = %index% + 1
goto firstnum_loop

:firstnum_end
( ENDLOCAL & REM RETURN VALUES
    IF "%~2" NEQ "" SET "%~2=%return_number%"
)
goto :eof

:isdigit
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set NUMBERS=1234567890
set found_number=false
call set "string=%%%~1%%"
REM If the passed string does not have a single character, return immediately with false.
if ("%string:~0,1%") == ("") goto isdigit_end
if not ("%string:~1,1%") == ("") goto isdigit_end
set /a index=0
goto isdigit_loop

:isdigit_loop
if ("!NUMBERS:~%index%,1!") == ("") goto isdigit_end
set test_char=!NUMBERS:~%index%,1!
if ("%test_char%") == ("%string%") set found_number=true&&goto isdigit_end
set /a index = %index% + 1
goto isdigit_loop

:isdigit_end
( ENDLOCAL & REM RETURN VALUES
    IF "%~2" NEQ "" SET "%~2=%found_number%"
)
goto :eof
```

Sample output:

```
C:\>extractfirstnumber c:\dir\release1\temp
1
C:\>extractfirstnumber c:\dir\release11\temp
11
C:\>extractfirstnumber c:\dir\release1\temp\rel2
1
C:\>extractfirstnumber c:\dir\release15a\temp
15
```

Comment: Is there a way to change this to get last number?

Comment: It crashes whenever it encounters a " symbol.