# Extract number from string in batch file

Tags: regex, batch-file

From a batch file I want to extract the number `653456` from the following string:

```
C:\Users\testing\AppData\Local\Test\abc123\643456\VSALBT81_COM
```

The number will change, however it will always be just digits.

My current theory is to search for something that fits `\alldigits\`, then replace the two `\`s with white space, but I can’t quite get it.

Comment: What is your code so far?

Comment: You should give some examples of stuff that shouldn't match too, e.g. `(^.*\\)([0-9]*)(\\.*$)` with `\2` to extract the second back reference works for the example above, but what if you have more than one folder with all digits?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming the number is always the parent folder (the folder before the end):

```
@echo off
set "str=C:\Users\testing\AppData\Local\Test\abc123\643456\VSALBT81_COM"
for %%F in ("%str%\..") do set "number=%%~nxF"
```

Comment: The reason this answer was chosen over the others (that were all correct also) - is this answer was safer for my scenario.

Answer (score 5):

EDIT - Code sample adapted to correct errors shown in comments

```
set d=C:\Users\testing\AppData\Local\Test\abc123\643456\VSALBT81_COM
for %%f in ("%d:\=" "%") do for /f %%n in ('echo %%f^|findstr /b /e /r "\"[0-9]*\""') do (
    echo %%~n
)
```

Just precede the path with a quote, split the path, replacing each backslash with a quote a space and a quote and append a quote (so we have a list of elements to iterate), and for each part check if it is formed only by numbers

Comment: +1, But space, `=`, or `;` could be in path name. Better to enclose parts in quotes using `for %%f in ("%d:\=" "%")`, and `echo %%~f` instead of `echo %%f`

Comment: I have discarded it just because the are not numbers, so no match will be returned, but you are right, a partial match can make it fail.

Comment: Exactly. For example, if \abc123\ were \abc 123\, then your code would fail as written. My modification would solve that problem.

Comment: Almost. Your modifications don't handle & inside path. I've updated the code to take care of it.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off 
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "string=C:\Users\testing\AppData\Local\Test\abc123\643456\VSALBT81_COM"

for /L %%d in (0,1,9) do set "string=!string:\%%d=\ %%d!"
for /F "tokens=2" %%a in ("%string%") do for /F "delims=\" %%b in ("%%a") do echo Number: [%%b]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I striped numbers from a string in batch (not a file path, should be generically working for a "string")

```
@ECHO OFF
::set mystring=Microsoft Office 64-bit Components 2013
set mystring=Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise - en-us
echo mystring = %mystring%
for /f "tokens=1-20 delims=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#$&*()-= " %%a in ("%mystring%") do (
   IF %%a == 64 (
     set ONum=%%b
     GoTo varset
   )
   IF %%a == 32 (
     set ONum=%%b
     GoTo varset
   )
   set ONum=%%a
)

:varset
echo numfromalphanumstr = %numfromalphanumstr%
pause
```

https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3499

https://superuser.com/questions/1065531/filter-only-numbers-0-9-in-output-in-classic-windows-cmd

[Extract number from string in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646834/extract-number-from-string-in-batch-file#comment122014887_19648045)

[How to extract number from string in BATCH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120623/how-to-extract-number-from-string-in-batch)