# parsing the file via batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, cmd

I want a command that prints just the number on a speficied line of a file that looks like this:

```
Total Time : 20.500 s
Speed download : 934155.000 b/s
Size of file :19150191 b
```

I can grep a whole line:

```
findstr "Total" C:\file.txt
```

but then I have the whole string `Total Time : 20.500 s`, but I need only `20.500`.

Comment: What do you want to do with the values? Display them? Store them in variables?

Comment: I need to have for example :
echo atatat.txt  .... ; and after that to get value 19150191, that's it

Comment: I guess this could solve your problem: [Extract number from string in batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19646834/2157640)

Comment: If the question I linked to in my previous comment solves your problem, please say so in a comment here. Also you can post an answer with the resulting code here.

Answer (score 2):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set x=1
for /f %%a in ('for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%i in (x.txt^) do @echo %%i') do (
 set val!x!=%%a
 set /a x+=1
)
set val
```

one `for` to split by `:`, another to split the second token by `<space>` to get rid of the units and the leading and trailing spaces.