# Best option to find last digits in a position of string with bat

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I have some cases where a string can take differents values:

`foto_20180601_1.jpg
 foto_20180601_10.jpg
 foto_20180601_100.jpg
 foto_20180601_1000.jpg`

If I want to get the last digit in those strings (`1, 10, 100, 1000`), I can make:

```
set var=%string:~14% (returns 1.jpg | 10.jpg | 100.jpg | 1000.jpg)
set mystring=%var:.jpg=% (removes '.jpg' and returns the number)
```

So I want to know if there is some improved way in which I can use `findstr` using `regex` to get those numbers too.

I have tried with something like this, but can't get it:

```
set string=foto_20180601_100.jpg
for %%f in ("%string:\=" "%") do for /f %%n in ('echo %%f^|findstr /b /e /r "*[0-9]*.jpg"') do (
    echo %%~n
)
```

Comment: If the structure of the file names is regular as in you samples use a `for /f` splitting at the underscore taking the last (3rd) token. Otherwise as the name implies findstr's (limited) RegEx capabilities are only useful for finding strings.

Comment: Yes I know, but I'm trying to adapt the code found here => [https://stackoverflow.com/a/19659283/2954267](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19659283/2954267), but can't get it. That's why I'm looking for help.

Comment: `grep` for Windows, PowerShell?

Comment: Off topic PowerShell: `ls "foto_*_*.jpg"|? Basename -match 'foto_\d{8}_(\d+)'|%{$matches[1]}` will list just the trailing numbers

Comment: Why are you trying to replace a backslash in your string? There is no backslash in your string!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit** New variation of your example

```
@Echo off
set string=foto_20180601_100.jpg
for %%f in (%string:_= %) do for /f "delims=." %%n in (
    'echo %%f^|findstr /i "^[0-9]*.jpg$" ') do echo %%~n
```

---

```
100
```

Modifying your last example (and using [aschipfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5047996/aschipfl)'s hint)

```
@Echo off
set string=foto_20180601_100.jpg
for %%f in (%string:_= %) do Set "Last=%%~nf"
Set Last
```

Sample output:

```
Last=100
```

PowerShell example

```
> ls foto*
    Verzeichnis: A:\

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       2018-06-02     00:26              2 foto_20180601_1.jpg
-a----       2018-06-02     00:26              2 foto_20180601_10.jpg
-a----       2018-06-02     00:26              2 foto_20180601_100.jpg
-a----       2018-06-02     00:26              2 foto_20180601_1000.jpg

PoSh 00:43:49 A:\______________________________________________________
> ls "foto_*_*.jpg"|? Basename -match 'foto_\d{8}_(\d+)'|%{$matches[1]}
1
10
100
1000
```

Comment: Yes, of course; it is a solution and works. Some ideas with my `regex` approach?

Comment: As already mentioned findstr can only filter on lines containing a RegEx. There are no advanced replace features/capture groups etc - this is a dead end. Use j-/vbscript/PowerShell for this.

Comment: Thanks my friend for your efforts in help, but can you please take a look here => [https://stackoverflow.com/a/19659283/2954267](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19659283/2954267). There is an approaching example of what I need.

Comment: Well that approach looked for a number somewhere in a path and used findstr to filter only numbers. It would also catch a date. I'll add a working version of that to my answer.

Comment: If you used `Set "Last=%%~nf"` you wouldn't have to truncate the `.jpg` extension later... anyway, +1!

Comment: @aschipfl Thanks for the hint, incorporated it.

Comment: @LotPings Thanks for your time, comments and answers adapted to my specific syntax. The `powershell` example was very helpfull too.

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```cmd
set "STRING=foto_20180601_100.jpg"
for %%I in ("%STRING:_=\%") do echo %%~nI
```

This replaces every `_` by `\`, which makes the file name appear as a relative path to the `for` loop; the `~n` modifier of the `for` variable extracts the pure name of the last element then, which is the part of interest.

To check whether the extracted portion is purely numeric, you could to this:

```cmd
set "STRING=foto_20180601_100.jpg"
for %%I in ("%STRING:_=\%") do (
    (for /F "delims=0123456789 eol=0" %%J in ("%%~nI") do rem/) && (
        echo %%~nI is NOT numeric
    ) || (
        echo %%~nI is purely numeric
    )
)
```