# Windows batch file extract number from filename

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have written a `for` loop in a Win7 batch file which runs through every file in a specified folder:

```
for /f %%f in ('dir /b C:\some_folder') do ( 
    echo %%f
)
```

The files are in this format `abc_123_1234567.txt`. How can I extract the last set of numbers (i.e. `1234567`) from the filename and put them in a variable?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120623/how-to-extract-number-from-string-in-batch

Take a look at the link.

Comment: Suppose there is more than one filename matching tha pattern. Which number do you want? Is the pattern always string_string_stringyouwant.ext?

Comment: This for loop will run through each file in-turn and so there is only ever one file it will have to consider to extract the numbers from.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this nicely using [JREN.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081) - a hybrid JScript/batch utility that renames files by performing a regular expression search and replace on the name. [JREN.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081) is pure script that will run natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

I use the `/T` test option so that it just lists the original file and the new name, without actually doing a rename. I then use FOR /F to parse the results to get the original name and the extracted number. It requires some arcane syntax to set the delimiter to a quote.

```
@echo off
for /f tokens^=1^,3^ delims^=^" %%A in (
  'jren ".*_\d+_(\d+)\.[^.]*$" "$1" /t /p "C:\some_folder"'
) do (
  echo File=%%A  Number=%%B
)
```

Comment: I've appended `$` to the search term to make the solution more precise.

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "tokens=3delims=_." %%f in ('dir /b C:\some_folder\*') do ( 
    set /a filenum=%%f
    echo %%f
)
echo filenum is %filenum%
```

Provided there is but one file matching the format you've provided