# How to request integer input from user in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, integer

I want to create a batch file on Windows that can let the user enter only a number between 1-31... I could use this number later in the batch file... It is possible ?

I tried this

```
set /P "month=Enter the month of the year : "
findstr /i %month% %file% | sort /+24
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But [what have you tried so far that isn't working](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: I tried with the SET /P command, but the user can enter letters and I don't want that...

Comment: You should update your question with the code that you've tried so far. Input from the console is inherently string based, so you can expect to get anything from a user. You will have to validate it yourself.

Comment: How can I validate it ? Do you have suggestions

Comment: After you've got your variable, check here regarding numeric validation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120623/how-to-extract-number-from-string-in-batch

Comment: There's only 12 months in a year BTW :-p

Answer (score 5):

```
@echo off
:try_again
set /P "month=Enter the month of the year : "
echo %month%|findstr /r "[^0-9]" && (
    echo enter a number
    goto :try_again
)
::clears the leading zeroes.
cmd /c exit /b %month%
set /a month=%errorlevel%
if %month% gtr 31  (
   echo enter a number between 1 and 31
   goto :try_again
)

if %month% lss 1 (
   echo enter a number between 1 and 31
   goto :try_again
)
```

?

Comment: Shouldn't that be 1 - 12 for month?

Comment: @ManoDestra the op says `between 1-31`

Comment: Didn't realize that there were 31 months in the year. OP must be wrong :-p Good solution.

Comment: @ThomasJomphe fails if user enters something like `2xy` (after your edit - npocmaka's original code covered that)

Comment: I'm afraid this fails if the user enters something like `08` or `09`...

Comment: @aschipfl - aah.Good point.Added a line that clears the leading zeroes.

Answer (score 3):

Well, these two options are *entirely different*:

- Let the user enter anything; then, check if the input is a number between 1 and 12 and retry the input if it is not.
- Let the user just enter a number between 1 and 12.

The Batch file below implement the second method:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

echo Precede numbers 1 and 2 by a zero
set /P "=Enter a month: " < NUL
choice /C 0123456789 > NUL
set /A "number=%errorlevel%-1"
if %number% gtr 1 echo %number% & goto continue
set /P "=%number%" < NUL
if %number% equ 0 (
   choice /C 12 > NUL
   set "digit2=!errorlevel!"
) else (
   choice /C 012 > NUL
   set /A "digit2=!errorlevel!-1"
)
echo %digit2%
set /A "number=number*10+digit2"
:continue

echo/
echo Number read: %number%
```

Comment: Allowing a preceding `0` for numbers from `2` to `9` optionally would appear more comfortable to me, but great approach anyway!

Answer (score 1):

A very simple but efficient method I use when I need a non-zero numeric input is the following code (note that this verifies the user entry afterwards):

```dos
:RETRY_RESET
rem /* Since zero is considered as invalid, preset variable to `0` to
rem    not keep the former value in case the user just presses ENTER;
rem    you could also define a non-zero default value here optionally: */
set /A NUMBER=0
:RETRY_REUSE
rem // Display prompt now:
set /P NUMBER="Please enter a positive number: "
rem /* Convert entry to a numeric value; everything up to the first
rem    numeral is converted to a numeric value, except leading SPACEs
rem    or TABs are ignored and signs `+` and `-` are recognised: */
set /A NUMBER+=0
rem /* Caution: numbers with leading `0` are converted to octal ones!
rem    since `8` and `9` are not valid octal numerals, entries with
rem    such figures and leading zeros are converted to `0`! */
rem // Verify entry:
if %NUMBER% EQU 0 goto :RETRY_RESET
rem // Do something with `%NUMBER%` at this point...
rem /* Afterwards you can jump to `:RETRY_RESET` to enter another number;
rem    alternatively, jump to `:RETRY_REUSE` to maintain the former entry
rem    in case the user just presses ENTER... */
```

This will not fail for any entry you can think of because the variable `NUMBER` holding the value is never expanded before it is converted to a true number by `set /A NUMBER+=0`.

The script recognises `+` and `-` signs correctly. Leading white-spaces are ignored. Besides all those, everything up to the first non-numeric figure is converted to a number; so for instance, an entry like <kbd>SPACE</kbd>`+15.75k` is converted to `15` as the `.` is not a numeral.

The disadvantage of this approach is that leading zeros may lead to unexpected results as `set /A` interpretes numbers with such as octal ones; so for instance, `012` is converted to (decimal) `10`, and `08` and `09` are converted to `0` as `8` and `9` are not valid octal digits.
A good point though could be the fact that hexadecimal numbers are recognised correctly in case they are prefixed with `0x`; for example, `0x18` is converted to `24`; `0xAS` becomes `10` (as `S` is not hex.).

Answer (score 1):

A safe and simple manner for performing this task is the use of the `Set /A` command in conjunction with the `||` conditional operator and a `:label` to return to for when invalid input is entered.

A number of tests can be performed on the input value using `set /a` without expanding the variables content in a manner that leaves your code vulnerable to code injection.

An example:

```bat
@Echo off

 Call:ValidNum $RV 31
 Call:ValidNum "" "" 5
 Set $

Goto:Eof

:ValidNum [returnvar] [max] [min]
SETLOCAL
Set "sign=-1"

 :VNumIn
 %= ensure nul value =%
  Set "input="
 %= define max value =%
  2> nul Set /a "max=%~2" || Set "max=2147483647"
 %= define min value =%
  2> nul Set /a "min=%~3" || Set "min=1"


  Set /p "input=Enter a number GEQ %min% LEQ %max%: "

 %= Input Testing. input +/-         , input > min     , input < max   , Hex/Octal for comparison =%
  2>nul Set /a "1/(sign-(input>>31))","max/(input/min)","1/(max/input)","HexOct=input" || Goto:VNumIn

 %= compare assignments to block hex, octal and leading 0's =%
  If not "%Input%"=="%HexOct%" Goto:VNumIn

( %= return value in $Num if no arg 1, else return in Arg1 =%
 ENDLOCAL & Set "%~1=%input%" 2> nul || Set "$Num=%input%"
 Goto:Eof
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following script is sort of a mixture of both restricting characters/key during entry and verifying characters/value after entry. The code is quite complex but it is very flexible and also safe. Here is it:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here (`findstr` reg. expr.):
set "WHITE=[0-9]" & rem // (positive list, accepted characters)
set "BLACK=[^`^]" & rem // (negative list, rejected characters)
set "LENGTH=2"    & rem // (optional limit for length of entry)

rem // resolve length limit:
set /A LENGTH-=1
if %LENGTH% LSS 0 set "LENGTH="

rem // Retrieve back-space character:
for /F %%C in ('echo prompt $H ^| cmd') do set "BS=%%C"

:HOOK
rem // Display prompt:
echo(Please enter something:
set "ENTRY="

:LOOP
rem // Use `xcopy /W` to capture a single key stroke:
set "KEY="
for /F "delims=" %%K in ('2^> nul xcopy /L /W "%~f0" "%~f0"') do (
    if not defined KEY set "KEY=%%K"
)
set "KEY=%KEY:~-1%"
rem // Leave loop in case ENTER has been pressed:
if not defined KEY goto :NEXT
rem // Disallow `"` to avoid syntax errors (`if`, no del. exp.):
set "KEY=%KEY:"=%" & rem "
rem // Disallow `=` to avoid syntax errors (`set /P`):
if "%KEY%"=="=" set "KEY="
rem // Disallow `   ` (tabulator):
if "%KEY%"=="   " set "KEY="
rem // Optional additional filter (include):
if defined WHITE (
    (echo("%KEY%" | > nul findstr /R /C:"%BS%" /C:"%WHITE%") || (
        set "KEY="
    )
)
rem // Optional additional filter (exclude):
if defined BLACK (
    (echo("%KEY%" | > nul findstr /R /C:^"\"%BLACK%\"^") || (
        set "KEY="
    )
)
rem // In general, display string equals pressed key:
set "DISPLAY=%KEY%"
rem // Avoid space in display text (ignored by `set /P`):
if "%KEY%"==" " set "DISPLAY=_%BS% "
rem // Force to clear preceding character upon back-space:
if "%KEY%"=="%BS%" (
    set "DISPLAY=%BS% %BS%"
    if defined ENTRY set "ENTRY=%ENTRY:~,-1%"
    set "KEY="
)
rem // Ignore any more character if length limit is reached:
set "TEST=%ENTRY%"
if defined LENGTH if defined ENTRY (
    call set "TEST=%%ENTRY:~,%LENGTH%%%"
)
if not "%TEST%"=="%ENTRY%" (
    set "KEY=" & set "DISPLAY="
)
set "ENTRY=%ENTRY%%KEY%"
rem // Show display text:
< nul set /P ="%DISPLAY%"
goto :LOOP

:NEXT
echo(
rem /* Verify the entry; for instance,
rem    check numeric value after removal of leading zeros: */
cmd /C exit %ENTRY%
set /A ENTRY=%ErrorLevel%
set /A ENTRY+=0 & rem // (conversion to true numeric value)
if %ENTRY% LEQ  0 goto :HOOK
if %ENTRY% GTR 12 goto :HOOK
rem // Do something with the entry (display):
echo(You entered this value:
< nul set /P ="%ENTRY%"
echo(

endlocal
exit /B
```

The core of the script is the `xcopy /L /W` command which takes a single key stroke (`/W`) and does no copying (`/L`). Its output is captured by a `for /F` loop to get the current key or character. For displaying `< nul set /P` is used with nothing sent into its prompt but the message text displayed, which is not terminated by a line-break unlike `echo`. Consult also the comments (`rem`) in the code.

The script can be configured in the `Define constants here` block at the top:

- variable `WHITE` defines a positive character set for the `findstr` command, one of which a character/key must equal; set to an empty string to disable this set; for our situation, `[0-9]` is suitable as it defines to accept only numeric figures;
- variable `BLACK` defines a negative character set for the `findstr` command, one of which a character/key must *not* equal; set to an empty string to disable this list; since there is already `WHITE` defined, `BLACK` is not needed; the first character within the brackets `[` `]` must be a caret `^` so that the given characters are truly rejected; if the sets in `WHITE` and `BLACK` overlap, the latter takes precedence;
- variable `LENGTH` defines the greatest length of the entry, so if the given number of characters have been supplied, no more are accepted; you can delete the last character though by the <kbd>←—</kbd> key; since we need a two-digit numeric value, `2` is the value of choice here;